# Amazon Lex SDK only running one command

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-lex

I am attempting to use the AWS SDK version 3 and the Lex Runtime client V2. ([Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-lex-runtime-v2/index.html))

What I don't understand is why can I not reuse my client instance to send multiple commands? See the code below. I am attempting to do a basic flow of putting a session, recognizing the text, and then deleting the session. When I comment the code out to run each command individually it works. Why does my application stop after running only the first client.send command? All the documentation ends up doing is creating a new client for each command because the examples are showing multiple services being used not the same service ([example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/lex-bot-example-script.html))

```
const {
  LexRuntimeV2Client,
  PutSessionCommand,
  RecognizeTextCommand,
} = require("@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-v2");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

require("dotenv").config();

const sessionCustomId = "12345678";

const getLexClient = () => {
  return new LexRuntimeV2Client({
    credentials: new AWS.Credentials(
      process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
      process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY
    ),
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  });
};

const main = async () => {
  await console.log(
    `******* ENV VARS *********\n\n AWS_REGION : ${process.env.AWS_REGION}\n DEWEY_ALIAS_ID : ${process.env.DEWEY_ALIAS_ID}\n DEWEY_BOT_ID : ${process.env.DEWEY_BOT_ID}\n LOCAL_ID : ${process.env.LOCALE_ID}\n\n`
  );

  /*******************************  PUT SESSION ***********************************/
  // a client can be shared by different commands.
  const client = await getLexClient();

  const putSessionCommand = new PutSessionCommand({
    accept: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
    botAliasId: process.env.DEWEY_ALIAS_ID,
    botId: process.env.DEWEY_BOT_ID,
    localeId: process.env.LOCALE_ID,
    sessionState: {},
    sessionId: sessionCustomId,
  });

  try {
    const response = await client.send(putSessionCommand);
    console.log("finished putting session\n");
    console.log(response);
    var chatSessionState = response.sessionState;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(
      "Error sending PutSessionCommand, error message: " + JSON.stringify(err)
    );
  }

  /*******************************  RECOGNIZE TEXT ***********************************/
  //get new client
  //var client = await getLexClient();

  const recognizeTextCommand = new RecognizeTextCommand({
    botAliasId: process.env.DEWEY_ALIAS_ID,
    botId: process.env.DEWEY_BOT_ID,
    localeId: process.env.LOCALE_ID,
    sessionState: {},
    sessionId: sessionCustomId,
    text: "Create a case",
  });

  try {
    const responseTwo = await client.send(recognizeTextCommand);
    console.log("finished posting text input\n");
    console.log(responseTwo);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(
      "Error sending RecognizeTextCommand, error message: " +
        JSON.stringify(err)
    );
  }

  /*******************************  DELETE SESSION ***********************************/
  const deleteSessionCommand = new DeleteSessionCommand({
    botAliasId: process.env.DEWEY_ALIAS_ID,
    botId: process.env.DEWEY_BOT_ID,
    localeId: process.env.LOCALE_ID,
    sessionId: sessionCustomId,
  });

  try {
    const responseThree = await client.send(deleteSessionCommand);
    console.log("finished deleting session\n");
    console.log(responseThree);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(
      "Error sending DeletingSession, error message: " + JSON.stringify(err)
    );
  }
};

main();
```

Comment: I ended up with code that gets a new lex client for each call to RecognizeText. Still wondering if this is how it is meant to be.